# Does Diablo III have cross-platform partnering?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just got Diablo III (yes, I'm late to the game) for the PS4. My wife has a Nintendo Switch and is thinking about getting Diablo III. Would it be possible to play with cross-platform partnering? If so, how?

If it matters, the two systems would be on the same wireless network.

Answer (score 21):

While cross-platform co-op is not supported in Diablo 3, you can definitely do couch co-op on the PS4. Both of you will be on the same screen (without splitting it in half like in some other co-op games) and it's very fun game to play together. You just need a second controller to do it.

Comment: Nintendo Switch does the same for couch co-op. Done it with four players.

Comment: ```Both of you will be on the same screen (without splitting it in half like in some other co-op games)``` this sounds like a nightmare. What happens when you go off screen

Comment: You cannot go offscreen ;) You can however block your partner from getting their loot if you are quick enough and run to the other end of the screen - the screen "locks" if both of you are trying to go in opposite directions - and hilarity will ensue.

Comment: Also, depending on the layout of your area, you can trap players with impassable terrain, usually leading to their demise.

Answer (score 17):

No, there is no cross platform play for Diablo III

Comment: I realize answers answer *questions* and you're not making a blanket statement, but are Mac and PC considered different platforms?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Mac and PC have never been considered separate platforms from a multiplayer standpoint with Blizzard games.

Comment: Logarr is correct. PC and Mac both count as 'computer' platforms so they CAN play together

Comment: I don't know about PS4 but the Switch version is apparently easily exploited based on the leaderboards, so they may not want to contaminate other versions with items generated via exploit on the Switch version.

Comment: Mac and Windows (typically referred to as 'PC') both fall under the banner of 'PC'